# Auto-incrementing attribute with custom logic in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, auto-increment

I have a simple "Invoices" class with a "Number" attribute that has to
be assigned by the application when the user saves an invoice. There
are some constraints:

1) the application is a (thin) client-server one, so whatever
assigns the number must look out for collisions
2) Invoices has a "version" attribute too, so I can't use a simple
DBMS-level autoincrementing field

I'm trying to build this using a custom Type that would kick in every
time an invoice gets saved. Whenever process_bind_param is called with
a None value, it will call a singleton of some sort to determine the
number and avoid collisions. Is this a decent solution?
Anyway, I'm having a problem.. Here's my custom Type:

```
class AutoIncrement(types.TypeDecorator):
   impl = types.Unicode

   def copy(self):
       return AutoIncrement()

   def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
       if not value:
           # Must find next autoincrement value
           value = "1" # Test value :)
       return value
```

My problem right now is that when I save an Invoice and AutoIncrement
sets "1" as value for its number, the Invoice instance *doesn't* get
updated with the new number.. Is this expected? Am I missing
something?
Many thanks for your time!

(SQLA 0.5.3 on Python 2.6, using postgreSQL 8.3)

**Edit:** Michael Bayer told me that this behaviour is expected, since TypeDecorators don't deal with default values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you don't just use a `default=` parameter in your column definition?  (This can be an arbitrary Python callable).

```
def generate_invoice_number():
    # special logic to generate a unique invoice number

class Invoice(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'invoice'
    number = Column(Integer, unique=True, default=generate_invoice_number)
    ...
```

Comment: Ouch didn't know you could use a callable there, thanks! I'll try it right away :)

Comment: Say your default callable returns the max of the column in the DB plus one. Is there any way to assert there are no race conditions without relying on a error from the column being unique?

Comment: In that case, you're better off writing your default as an inline SQL expression.  This is covered in detail in the SQLAlchemy documentation at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/metadata.html#pre-executed-and-inline-sql-expressions

Comment: You are going to get race conditions even with SQL expressions, it only makes the race window smaller. To avoid races you need locking, either explicit table level or row level via select for update.

Comment: Are you certain you'll get race conditions if your insert is a single statement (as it will be if you use an SQL expression as a default)?  I was under the impression that single statements typically execute atomically.

Comment: Since only the serverside part of my application has access to the DB, I used a simple locking system.. I have a multithreaded testcase that hammers on the server and then checks the generated values afterwards, it looks ok... Am I missing something? ^^;