# making the auto increment IDs start by a predefined number

Tags: sqlalchemy

I was asked to make the ids of our equipement start with the current year (eg : 21-4234 instead of just 4234) and I was wondering if this was possible. This is how we make the ids for our equipement:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

if anyone knows how this can be achieved i would love to hear from you :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-incrementing attribute with custom logic in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038126/auto-incrementing-attribute-with-custom-logic-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: I will try this right away in the morning but seeing how this works it should perfectly do the trick!! Thank you very much I'll keep you updated tomorrow :-)